# Erro em insert Entity Framekwork - MySQl

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao tentar realizar o SaveChanges():

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

Código:

```
try
            {
                if (curriculumVitae.DataUltimaAtualizacao == null)
                {
                    curriculumVitae.DataUltimaAtualizacao = DateTime.ParseExact(
                        String.Format("{0} {1}", cvXml.DATAATUALIZACAO, cvXml.HORAATUALIZACAO),
                        Utils.ParseDateFormat(cvXml.FORMATODATAATUALIZACAO) + " %Hmmss",
                        null
                    );
                }

                var professor = this.ProcurarProfessorPorNumeroCurriculo(curriculumVitae.NumeroCurriculo);

                if (professor != null && professor.DataUltimaAtualizacaoCurriculo >= curriculumVitae.DataUltimaAtualizacao)
                {
                    Logger.Info(String.Format(
                        "Currículo {0} do Professor {1} já esta na última versão.",
                        curriculumVitae.NumeroCurriculo,
                        curriculumVitae.NomeProfessor
                    ));
                    return true;
                }

                ProcessarCache(cvXml);

                if (professor != null)
                {
                    RemoverDadosProfessor(professor);
                }
                else
                {
                    // criar o professor
                    professor = LattesDatabase.Professor.Create();
                    criarProfessor = true;
                }

                // dados do curriculo
                professor.NumeroCurriculo = curriculumVitae.NumeroCurriculo;
                professor.LinkParaCurriculo = String.Format("http://lattes.cnpq.br/{0}", professor.NumeroCurriculo);

                professor.DataUltimaAtualizacaoCurriculo = (DateTime)curriculumVitae.DataUltimaAtualizacao;

                professor.DataUltimaPublicacaoCurriculo = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1); // data qualquer no passado

                ProcessarDadosGerais(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarEnderecosEContatos(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarIdiomas(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarPremiosETitulos(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarFormacaoAcademicaETitulacao(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarAreasAtuacaoProfessor(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarProducoesTecnicasEPatentes(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarProducoesBibliograficas(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarParticipacaoEventos(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarOrientacoesESupervisoes(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarBancasDeTrabalho(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarBancasJulgadoras(professor, cvXml);

                ProcessarAtuacoesProfissionaisEProjetos(professor, cvXml);

                if (criarProfessor)
                {
                    LattesDatabase.Professor.Add(professor);
                }
                LattesDatabase.SaveChanges(); 
                CriarBaseDeConsulta(professor);
                LattesDatabase.SaveChanges(); // salva base de consulta
                return true;
            }
```

Stack:

```
    2019-05-06 14:40:38,448 [5] ERROR ProfessorDAOService - Exceção: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   em System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   em LattesExtractor.DAO.ProfessorDAOService.ProcessCurriculumVitaeXML(CurriculoVitaeXml cvXml, CurriculoEntry curriculumVitae) na C:\Users\Unisc\source\ExtratorLattesCNPq\LattesExtractor\DAO\ProfessorDAOService.cs:linha 257
2019-05-06 14:40:38,448 [5] ERROR ProfessorDAOService - Exceção Interna [1]: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

Algumas tabelas do banco são recebem inserções/atualizações, mas as que tem relação com a tabela Professor não acontece nada (se eu insiro manualmente na tabela Professor o id é definido como se tivessem registros na tabela, mesmo não tendo nenhum)

Comment: Boa tarde, @Ander_. Apenas tentando entender, qual a necessidade de escrever 

LattesDatabase.SaveChanges();

 2x no mesmo bloco?

Se for para salvar as alterações do bloco:

if (criarProfessor), não tem necessidade, ok?

Tenta invocar o método SaveChanges() apenas no final de todo o processo.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pude entender do seu código, a instância do contexto do banco de dados está acontecendo depois de ser executado o comando de persistência.
Além disso o comando de persistência está sendo executado duas vezes. o Ideal é que seja executado apenas uma única vez, esta fará toda a execução necessária de operação no banco.

Você percebe que o id do banco de dados progrediu por que houve uma tentativa de inserção, isto "consome" um id mesmo que a inserção não seja bem sucedida.

Uma coisa a ser verificada é se existe algum objeto nulo. Pois caso haja algum objeto nulo a execução não será realizada, mas quem faz essa validação é o banco de dados (consome um id). Nesse caso como há mais de um, uma das execuções pode ter sido vem sucedida.

Espero ter ajudado.